# What is a "non-trivial" example of a commutative algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a commutative connected algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. A theorem of Serre says that there exists an exact sequence
$$1\to \mathbb{G}_a^n\times \mathbb{G}_m^m\to G\to A\to 1,$$
where $A$ is an abelian variety. (See [here](https://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/sp-s12-w3/On_Mordell-Lang_in_algebraic_groups_of_unipotent_rank_1_%5D_Paul_Vojta,_University_of_California,_Berkeley.pdf), for example.)

**I wonder what are some examples of such groups $G$ where this extension is non-trivial. That is, such that $G\ncong \mathbb{G}_a^n\times \mathbb{G}_m^m\times A$.**

Comment: If you allow this to be split after passing to a finite covering, you can take $G_m$ times an elliptic curve and mod out by a nontrivial "diagonal" finite cyclic subgroup. Then it's not split (although a finite cover splits). This little game can't be performed with $G_a$.

Comment: The total space of the universal torsor over the relative $\text{Pic}^0$ of any smooth projective variety with nontrivial Picard gives an example.

Comment: Dear @JasonStarr would you mind explaining more?

Comment: Doesn't any line bundle on an abelian variety, which is algebraically equivalent to $0$ but not trivial give an example? (by taking the associated $\theta$ group).

Comment: Yes, I was trying to say what @DamianRoessler said.  There are nontrivial invertible sheaves over Abelian varieties, and these give examples.  There is even a “universal torsor” defined over the product of the Abelian variety with its relative $\text{Pic}^0$.

Comment: @JasonStarr. Quite - your example is the "universal" one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One example is provided by the generalized Jacobian. For a smooth projective curve $C$ and a divisor $D$ on $C$, the generalized Jacobian is defined to be the moduli space parameterizing pairs consisting of a line bundle of degree $0$ on $C$ together with a trivialization of that line bundle over $D$.

This admits a map to the usual Jacobian, whose kernel is a product of $\mathbb G_m$s and $\mathbb G_a$s depending on the multiplicity of points of $D$.

If this were trivial, than we could define a section of this map, which would give for an arbitrary line bundle a canonical trivialization at each point of $D$. That would mean that for each point $x\in D$, the line bundle on the usual Jacobian whose fiber at a point $L \in J$ is the fiber of $L$ at $x$ would admit a section and thus be trivial. But from the duality theory of abelian varieties, these line bundles are different for distinct points $x\in C$, so they cannot all be trivial as long as $D$ contains two or more points.

Comment: Dear @WillSawin, that's incredible. Since I never studied generalized Jacobians, do you have a simple example of it in mind?

Comment: @Gabriel I guess the simplest example would be the generalized Jacobian associated to two points on a curve of genus $1$, which is an extension of that elliptic curve by $\mathbb G_m$. As a scheme, it is some nontrivial degree-0 line bundle on the elliptic curve with the zero-section removed, but it carries a group structure.

Comment: Can you get both non-split extensions with kernel $G_a$ and $G_m$?

Comment: @Ycor The argument I gave shows that extension by $\mathbb G_m$ produced by generalized Jacobians when the divisor $D$ contains two different points are nontrivial, but I believe taking the derivative of this argument shows that extensions by $\mathbb G_a$ produced by generalized Jacobians when $D$ contains a point of multiplicity $\geq 2$ are nontrivial.

Comment: Also, do your examples remain non-split on every finite cover? (I'm mentioning, as a comment to the question, a non-split example which by construction becomes split after passing to a finite connected cover.)

Comment: @YCor If the multiplicities are one then difference between any two points of $D$ Is torsion in the Jacobian then this torsor will split after passing to a finite cover. If this is not true, it won't split. A non-split extension by $\mathbb G_a$ never becomes split after passing to a finite cover, I don't think.

Comment: Yes indeed: since starting from $G_a^n\times A$, $A$ abelian variety, every finite normal subgroup is contained in $A$ and hence the quotient also splits.

Comment: I changed a $C$ to a $D$ at the end of the first paragraph, you might want to check that I got it right.